# Docker environment variables in php

Tags: php, docker

How do I use the variables defined in Docker for use in PHP?

Example in Docker:

```
$ docker run -d my_container -e MYSQL_CONNECT="{host:'x', port:'x'}"
```

Example in PHP:
 `$_ENV['MYSQL_CONNECT']`

I've searched, but could not find anything concrete.

Comment: Your example works for me using the official PHP image: `docker run -it -e TEST=yes php:7.0.0 php -r 'echo $_ENV['TEST'];'`. What specifically are you having trouble with? Can you post some debugging information (error messages, Dockerfile, example)?

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide the environment variables before the image name, like this:

```
$ docker run -d -e MYSQL_CONNECT="{host:'x', port:'x'}" my_container
```